# How could I store decimals in a collection c#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program that could catch user input of string type. Every time there is a space within this string, the program needs to get that part of the string and try to parse it to a decimal. The entries might be numbers that might be separated by a comma rather than just plain integers, that is why I would be using decimals instead of integers.

This is what I tried so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("C# Exercise!" + Environment.NewLine);
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter two numbers seperated by space to start calculating: ");
    string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    //Currently allows for more than one value... I am not necessarily looking for a solution to this problem however.
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Result: ");
    //Create the collection of decimals:
    decimal[] numbers = { };
    numbers[0] = 1.0m;//<-- Results in a System.IndexOutOfRangeException
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input[i]);//<-- This value needs to be converted to a decimal and be added to a collection of decimals
    }
    /*decimal numberOne = ?? //<-- First decimal in the collection of decimals
    decimal numberTwo = ?? //<-- Second decimal in the collection of decimals
    Console.WriteLine(SumTrippler.Calculate(numberOne, numberTwo));*/
    Console.WriteLine(SumTrippler.Calculate(decimal.Parse("0.5"), (decimal)0.5));//<-- Irrelevant method
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

How could I get two decimals as user input from the user and process this data by passing it to the method at the bottom of my program?

Edit: Closing this question because you are trying to relate a question that adds a string to a list is not a solid reason. I am not trying to add a string to a list.

Comment: [`Decimal.TryParse(input[i], out someLocalDecimalVariable)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8), then do as you like with someLocalDecimalVariable. And start by creating an array big enough to hold all the decimals you'll need -- or better yet, create a `List<decimal>` and call `Add()` on it to add numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array.ConvertAll()` to convert string into decimal

```
var numbers = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), decimal.Parse);
//Now you can iterate through decimal array
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
}
```

Your code will look like,

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("C# Exercise!");
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter two numbers seperated by space to start calculating: ");
    var numbers = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), decimal.Parse);

    Console.WriteLine("Result: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
    }
    decimal numberOne = numbers.FirstOrDefault(); 
    decimal numberTwo = numbers.LastOrDefault(); //Your second element will be last element in array
    Console.WriteLine(SumTrippler.Calculate(numberOne, numberTwo));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for: `decimal[] numbers = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), decimal.Parse);`

Comment: @Barrosy, I am glad it works for you

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize the array with the required number of fields (which can't be changed afterwards)

```
decimal[] numbers = new decimal[input.Length];
numbers[0] = 1.0m; // no more System.IndexOutOfRangeException
```

Comment: I am not even sure if this is the supposed way to convert whatever `Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');` returns to a collection of decimals, but I will try and see if this will be helpful.

Comment: I kinda misunderstood this question I thought it was about the `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Comment: Yes, I pointed that out specifically just to help you guide you through my question as it might have been something to do with the initial problem. Any information provided helped with the end result.